# Docker RabbitMQ and Spring doesn't create password with new user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, rabbitmq

I'm trying to deploy a spring app with rabbitmq. I get a Connection Refused Error When  I use the default `user:password` (`guest:guest`) but when the user is created it makes it without password

```
Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#60d8c0dc:5/SimpleConnection@358e0edb [delegate=amqp://guest@192.168.64.2:5672/, localPort= 53472]
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "guest"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "guest"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672" #JMS Port
      - "15672:15672" #Management Port - default user:pass = guest:guest
    networks:
      - rabbit_mq

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "hospital"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - mysql_bridge
    restart: always

  springboot-docker-compose-app-container:
    image: app-image
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/hospital?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - db
    volumes:
      - /data/VerzorgerSOAP
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - mysql_bridge
      - rabbit_mq

networks:
  mysql_bridge:
  rabbit_mq:
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot provides default values for some application [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html):

```
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
```

In this case, it is only a coincidence.

Change these properties to something else and you will see that the auth will fail.